# Excel VBA Date Data Type Overflow (#6) Error

Tags: vba, class, date, object, overflow

I've recently been having a problem that occurs in an apparent random fashion as an Overflow Error (#6) when trying to retrieve the value of a property of a class that I created. The property is of the type Date and the private member has no problem being set properly, but when I try to get the property, it throws the overflow error. It is being called with the `Me.PropertyName` syntax from within the class definition and storing that value as a string. Here is the code:

```
Private pdFlightDate As Date

...

Property Get Item() As String
    Dim s As String
    s = Me.Count & "," & Me.FlightDate & "," & Me.Aircraft.Model & ","

...

Property Let FlightDate(pd As Date)
    pdFlightDate = pd
End Property
Property Get FlightDate() As Date
    FlightDate = pdFlightDate
End Property
```

The code is being run if Office 365 on a Mac running Big Sur. The data type overflow error did not occur two days ago when testing it, but it happened today persistently and I am at a loss to figure out what is causing the problem.

EDIT: showed the declaration of pdFlightDate

Comment: You need to show us your declaration for pdflightdate

Comment: So I fiddled with the calling function that just called Me.FlightDate and added it to a string, Excel crashed, and when I reopened it the code worked. So I don't know what happened to make this work but I'm not complaining about it.